# Is a space within a work of fiction rendered 'off the page' (referred to but unseen/non-existent) part of the work's paratext?

Tags: terminology, theory

For example, in *A Streetcar named Desire* Blanche and Stella's family's plantation 'Belle Reve' figures as an important space within the text, but isn't rendered directly in it - it is 'off the page', referenced but unseen. Is this rendering paratextual? Or is there a better/correct theoretical word to refer to spaces in texts which are not 'there' but are present in the imagination of the work, reader, and author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

No, that is not what *paratext* means. The most specific term for unseen places mentioned in a literary work is *offstage* locations. But the term you really want is *storyworld*, which refers to the imaginative spatial and temporal world created by the work.

### Deets

Gérard Genette distinguishes between **text** and **paratext** as follows:

> L'ouvre littéraire consiste, exhaustivement ou essentiellement, en un texte, c'est-à-dire (définition très minimale) en une suite plus ou moins longue d'énoncés verbaux plus ou moins pourvus de signification. Mais ce texte se présente rarement à l'état nu, sans le renfort et l'accompagnement d'un certain nombre de productions, elles-mêmes verbales ou non, comme un nom d'auteur, un titre, un préface, des illustrations ... Cet accompagnement, d'ampleur et d'allure variables, constitue ... le *paratexte* de l'œuvre.
>
> <sub>Genette, Gérard. [*Seuils*](https://archive.org/details/seuils0000grar/mode/2up). Paris: Éditions du Seuil, 1987. Accessed on archive.org 16 March 2024. [p. 7](https://archive.org/details/seuils0000grar/page/n7/mode/2up)</sub>
>
> A literary work consists, entirely or essentially, of a text, defined (very minimally) as a more or less long sequence of verbal statements that are more or less endowed with significance. But this text is rarely presented in an unadorned state, unreinforced and unaccompanied by a certain number of verbal or other productions, such as an author's name, a title, a preface, illustrations. ... These accompanying productions, which vary in extent and appearance, constitute ... the work's *paratext*.
>
> <sub>Genette, Gérard. [*Paratexts: Thresholds of Interpretation*](https://archive.org/details/gerardgenettejanee.lewinparatextsthreshozlib.org/mode/2up). Trans. Jane E. Lewin. Foreword Richard Macksey. Cambridge, UK: Cambridge UP, 1997. Accessed on archive.org 16 March 2024. [p. 1](https://archive.org/details/gerardgenettejanee.lewinparatextsthreshozlib.org/page/n25/mode/2up).</sub>

So the **paratext** is *ancillary material* that circulates around the text. This printed material can be non-verbal, such as illustrations and cover art. It can be verbal, such as a foreword, bibliography, etc. A songbook might have as paratext a website with recordings of the songs. For a novel, the author bio on the back cover or inside flap of the dust jacket is part of the paratext. Reviews, interviews with the author, scholarly articles, etc. that discuss the novel are all part of its paratext. In all cases, however, the paratext has an existence in the world of the author and the reader. Genette says:

> Le paratexte est donc pour nous ce par quoi un texte se fait livre et se propose comme tel à ses lecteurs, et plus généralement au public.
>
> <sub>Genette, [*Seuils*](https://archive.org/details/seuils0000grar/mode/2up), [pp. 7–8](https://archive.org/details/seuils0000grar/page/n7/mode/2up).</sub>
>
> For us, accordingly, the paratext is what enables the text to become a book and to be offered as such to its readers and, more generally, to the public.
>
> <sub>Genette, [*Paratexts*](https://archive.org/details/gerardgenettejanee.lewinparatextsthreshozlib.org/mode/2up) [p. 1](https://archive.org/details/gerardgenettejanee.lewinparatextsthreshozlib.org/page/n25/mode/2up)</sub>

The paratext is therefore not part of the *imagined* world of the text. It is what mediates between the text and the *real* world in which it circulates *as* a text.

Places such as Belle Rêve, on the other hand, are part of the imagined world of the text. The [Glossary of Narrative Terms](https://books.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0187/tables.xhtml) offers **storyworld**:

> The world of the story, which includes different types of existents (events, environments, and characters).

Erin James has a longer description:

> [S]cholars define a storyworld as a mental model of context and environment within which a narrative's characters function. Like the similar terms *story* and *fabula*, *storyworld* is a term narrative theorists use to discuss what happens in the narrative. But more so than other terms, the storyworld highlights the world-making power of narrative texts. Storyworld scholars argue that narrative comprehension relies upon readers interpreting textual cues to make mental models of a text's world and inhabiting those models emotionally. To understand a narrative, such scholars suggests, we *must* lose ourselves in the same environment and experiences as a narrative's characters.
>
> <sub>James, Erin. [*The Storyworld Accord: Econarratology and Postcolonial Narratives.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G0_9CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) Lincoln: U of Nebraska P, 2015. Accessed on books.google.com 16 March 2024. p. x.</sub>

The term *storyworld* is not restricted to individual spaces such as Belle Rêve, but refers to the entire imagined world created by the writer, which would encompass not only the offstage Belle Rêve, but also the New Orleans apartment building where the onstage action takes place, the hotel where Blanche has been a prostitute, etc. It constitutes the entire spatial and temporal milieu within which the characters operate, and in which the reader or spectator imaginatively participates.

Your question asks specifically about spaces in texts that are not "there." I'm not sure in what sense *any* fictional space is "there" as opposed to "not there." In Chekov's *Three Sisters*, for example, Moscow is very much part of the storyworld. But the thematic relevance lies in the fact that the play's setting is *not* Moscow. Even though Moscow is alluringly offstage throughout, one can hardly claim Moscow isn't "there" and is merely a made-up location. Similarly, the New Orleans apartment of the Kowalskis in *Streetcar* is certainly part of a realistic stage set, but it isn't "there" in the sense of being a real apartment. From the perspective of storyworld, the distinction between onstage and offstage is irrelevant. Belle Rêve is just as much a part of the storyworld of the play as the apartment is.

So if for some reason you are looking specifically for a word to describe locations important to but not visited by characters in a narrative, then [offstage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236448/a-novel-book-equivalent-of-the-term-off-screen) would be your best bet. But as far as spaces in texts which are "present in the imagination of the work, reader, and author," the appropriate term is storyworld.